# Не сохраняет предыдущий submit

Tags: php

```
    for($i=0;$i<=3;$i++){
    if(isset($_POST['get'.$i])){
      echo '<center>';
      echo '<form form action="" class="grform" method="post">';
      echo '<select   class="grupeTeam" name="ff'.$i.'">';
      echo '<option>Чебурашка</option>';
      echo '</select>';
      echo '<select   class="grupeLigue" name="gf'.$i.'">';
      echo '<option>Чебурашка</option>';
      echo '</select>';
      echo  '<input type="submit" name="final'.$i.'" class="redact">';  
      echo '</form>';
      echo '</center>';
    }else{ 
    echo '<form action="" method="post">';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="get'.$i.'" class="redact">';
    echo '</form>';}}
```

когда я нажимаю на submit появляется форма, но когда я нажимаю на следующий, то прошлый забывается

Comment: А почему он должен сохраняться? У вас в коде нет ничего, намекающего на сохранение предыдущего

Comment: Каждый раз, когда форма отправляется, формируется новый список параметров. Если какие-то из параметров нужно повторить, это нужно делать специально. Можете воспользоваться [скрытыми полями](https://webref.ru/html/input/type), чтобы хранить текущие значения флагов.

Comment: http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke